# Finding the "hidden values".

Tags: matrices, functional-equations

I have this problem but my knowledge of the methods of linear algebra is totally useless if it exists at all (I know what is a matrix at least... maybe).

I have a three collections of objects ${\bf a}\in A$, ${\bf w}\in W$ and ${\bf b} \in B$ and I have a process that takes a triple and automatically gives me a vector of natural number $F:A\times W \times B\to\Bbb N^3$.

$$ F({\bf a},{\bf w},{\bf b})
=
 \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_1\\  \sigma_2\\ \sigma_3 \end{pmatrix} 
$$

- I know that each element of  $A$, $W$ and $B$ have to be vectors so that we have $A\subseteq X^3$, $W\subseteq X^3$ and $B\subseteq X^3$ for some set of numbers $X\subseteq \Bbb Q$

$${\bf a}=\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\  a_2\\ a_3 \end{pmatrix} ;
{\bf w}=\begin{pmatrix} w_1\\  w_2\\ w_3 \end{pmatrix} {\text{  and   }}
{\bf b}=\begin{pmatrix} b_1\\  b_2\\ b_3 \end{pmatrix} 
$$

- I also know that the values of $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ and $\sigma_3$ belong to the set $5:=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$
- and I also know that $F$ is evaluated using an unknown $3$-ary function $f:\Bbb Q^3\to \Bbb N$ so that

$${\rm F}\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & w_1 & b_1 \\  a_2 & w_2 & b_2  \\ a_3 & w_3 & b_3  \end{pmatrix}
=
 \begin{pmatrix} f(a_1,w_1,b_1)=\sigma_1\\  f(a_2,w_2,b_2)=\sigma_2\\ f(a_3,w_3,b_3)=\sigma_3 \end{pmatrix} 
$$

The problem is that the values of every vector ${\bf a}\in A$, ${\bf w}\in W$ and ${\bf b} \in B$ are "**hidden**" (I can't see7know them) and I can only see the values $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ and $\sigma_3$, the outcome of $ F({\bf a},{\bf w},{\bf b})$.

**Questions:**

> Given only the behaviour of $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ and $\sigma_3$ (varying the arguments of $F$) how much it is possible to understand about the values of the vectors ${\bf a}\in A$, ${\bf w}\in W$ and ${\bf b} \in B$ and of $f$?
>
> What it's needed in order to solve the functional equation (find $f$) in an unique way?

Comment: Are the arguments hidden, but you can combine them as you like? For instance, can you compute $F(a_0,w_0,b_0)$, $F(a_1,w_1,b_1)$ and then $F(a_0+a_1,w_0+w_1,b_0+b_1)$? This would let you check for linearity; if you have linearity, then your problem is somewhat tractable.

Comment: @Ian I can combine as I like in the sense that I can freely evaluate $F$ for every triple $({\bf a},{\bf w},{\bf b})$ but the vector of rational number associated with each ${\bf a},{\bf w}$ and ${\bf b}$ is unknown/hidden.
I suppose that the function $f(x,y,z)$ that $F$ uses to give the triple of natural numbers is $\lfloor x+y+z \rfloor$ or something like that but I need a way to extract more information from $F$...I need a way extract  the vector's entries of every ${\bf a},{\bf w}$ and ${\bf b})$... if it is possible.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question: can you choose a new triple of arguments as a function of a previous triple of arguments?

Comment: no because since I don't know the numeric values hidden behind each ${\bf a},{\bf w}$ and ${\bf b}$, that are the only arguments of $F$ that I can chose, I don't know a way to understand if, for example, the triple $({\bf a},{\bf w},{\bf b})$ is the of the form $({\bf a}_0,{\bf w}_0,{\bf b}_0)+({\bf a}_1,{\bf w}_1,{\bf b}_1)$.
I'm sorry if I still don't understand.

Comment: Then I don't know how you would ever learn anything about $F$ besides getting some idea of its range.

Comment: Me too @Ian , It is an hard problem...I guess that it has infinite solutions anyways...but its a common problem that is related to videogames...or better, is related to videogamers. When I have more time I'll add more context.